# Can't add method prototype to JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

I was messing around with Javascript prototypes, and I don't understand why this works:

```
function User(un) {
    this.username = un;
}

User.prototype.method_name = function() {
    return this.username;
};

var user = new User("Michael");

console.log(user.method_name());
```

But this doesn't:

```
function User(un) {
    this.username = un;
    return{
        getUsername: function (){
            return username;
        },
        setUsername: function(username) {
            username = un;
        }
    };
}

User.prototype.method_name = function() {
    return this.username;
};

var user = new User("Michael");    
console.log(user.method_name());
```

Why does adding the "return" statement throw `Object #<Object> has no method 'method_name'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning an object circumvents the usual return value of a constructor, which is the `this` variable. Instead of returning `this`, you're returning some other object, and that object doesn't have a username property or a method_name method. This is roughly what happens at each point in the code:

```
function User(un) {
    this.username = un; // puts username on the 'this' object

    // returns an entirely different, unrelated object that doesn't use User's prototype
    return{
        getUsername: function (){
            return un;
        },
        setUsername: function(username) {
            un = username;
        }
    };
}

// sets method_name on the prototype of the 'this' object for User
User.prototype.method_name = function() {
    return this.username;
};

var user = new User("Michael"); // passes a new User.prototype as the implicit 'this' in the User function   
console.log(user.method_name());
```

Instead, try this:

```
function User(un) {
    this.username = un;
    this.getUsername = function (){
        return un;
    };
    this.setUsername = function(username) {
        un = username;
    };
}
User.prototype.method_name = function() {
    return this.username;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Because in the second example, the object you return isn't a new "User" instance, but a plain Object instance.

When you use the *new* key word with a constructor, the object returned by default inherits from the constructor's *prototype*, so you have an inheritance chain like:

```
user -> User.prototype -> Object.prototype -> null
```

If you return some other object, it doesn't inherit from the constructor and you have an inheritance chain like:

```
user -> Object.prototype -> null
```

Comment: +1, also OP the behavior for returning objects from a constructor is defined at step 9 of [ES5 #13.2.2](http://es5.github.io/#x13.2.2)

Comment: Doesn't the first example return also, just undefined? I don't see why explicitly returning something has an effect on how `new` operates.

Comment: @M1Reeder—in non–strict mode, a function called with *new* **must** return an object, so if you don't specify one, or attempt to return a primitive, it returns the object referenced by *this*, which is the new instance. If you do return some other object, then it isn't an instance.